# Regex for ignoring a character in a search

Tags: python, mysql, regex, django

I have a requirement where I need to match text like "testuser" or "joeperson" to data like "test.user" or "joe.person". I won't know where the period is in the incoming search term in the actual data. In short, we've got URLs like **/cart/[user name which can have a period]/items/** and I need to search for all usernames that match that pattern.

I'm using Django and Python against a MySQL database. I know that I can do a Django query like:

User.objects.filter(username__regex='[some crazy pattern]') but it's the crazy pattern I need help with.

Thanks so much!

Comment: cant you just remove periods from the string and then do a regular search with your new, sanitized string?

Comment: No, the data in the database may have a period, and it is considered correct. It's the search term that won't have a period.

Comment: Why don't you keep the database data in a normlized form without a period? Regular expressions will be slow.

Comment: @NiklasB. yes that would work, but in this case we don't have access to this database. So I have to kinda fudge it.

Comment: The easiest solution I see is something like `WHERE REPLACE(your_column, '.', '') = 'your_username_without_periods'`, but it is going to be grossly inefficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an SQL query like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE REPLACE(username, '.', '') = 'username_without_dots'
```

Or in Django:

```
normalized_name = searchterm.replace('.', '')
User.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM user WHERE '
                 'REPLACE(username, '.', '') = %s', 
                 [normalized_name])
```

Comment: Which is going to be really inefficient since you can't have index on calculated columns with MySQL. OP should probably make a second column for usernames without periods, but since he can't modify his database...

Comment: @VincentSavard: Yes, it's inefficient, but without the ability to change the data, I think it's the only way (at least better than regular expressions ;)

Comment: And cross your fingers not to have both paul.omaha paulo.maha in your table!

Comment: @sidyll: Heh, yes, yet another reason to keep the data in normalized form.

Comment: Thanks @NiklasB. this works. I was hoping to use regex and have it be faster but this will do fine.

Answer (score 1):

Edited for more concise use of '?' vs '{0,1}'

The real problem of course is that who/whatever is handing the field lookups off to you didn't prep it properly but regEx isn't necessarily going to be that much slower than looping the entire collection with a literal string.

RegEx matching is consecutive so you'd have to do something like this for 'testuser' where '.' characters between letters are optional. This actually isn't that slow of a regEx since it should fail the second a character doesn't match and all characters are explicit so you're not running down a massive index for every character.

```
r'^t\.?e\.?s\.?t\.?u\.?s\.?e\.?r$'
```

The part that matters is the space between your normal characters. For >=0 '.' characters you could do .*  and of course I'm assuming no periods beginning or end. If you can concatenate, you should be able to handle that.

To create the first regEx I would do something like:

```
user = user.split('')
userRegEx = '\.?'.join(user)

#not sure I have the right syntax for the Django arg

User.objects.filter(username__regex=r'^'+userRegEx+'$')
```

As a JS guy, I have to say I'm a little puzzled as to why it hasn't occurred to the Python community that both strings AND lists could have a .join method.

Comment: Also if you can be certain the first char won't be a '.' narrowing down with a 'starts with with first letter' query of some sort first might reduce the workload a bit.

Comment: Come on, you can replace each `\.{0,1}` with `\.?`.

Comment: Totally forgot about that single-character use. I just thought of it as the lazy toggler for multi-character matches. I'll edit.

Comment: Re your last comment: Haha, guess it didn't occur to you to try it out: Strings are "iterables", so you can say `r"\.".join("hello there")` and it Just Works. I simplified your solution.

Comment: Interesting. Same in JS but you still have to put an empty string in the args.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a backslash to escape the period in your regular expression, like this:

```
# This will work for test.user or joe.person
re.search('(\S+)\.(\S+)', 'test.user')
```